# How to access values in array of an object whom is in array within array

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I have a task to print out each person within json file with requirement errands, I have to access their direct friends (Friend array within each person) and there are IDs of each person. When I choose a person it prints me only person's friends, and now I need access friends of friends (friends of friends of chosen person).

Task is this: Friends of friends - those who are two steps away from the chosen user but not directly connected to the chosen user, can someone help me with this?

```
<script> 
class Osoba{
constructor(id,firstName,surname,age,gender,friends){
    this._id = id ;
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._surname = surname;
    this._age = age;
    this._gender = gender;
    this._friends = friends;
    }

    get id() {
        return this._id;
    }
    set id(id){
        this._id = id;
    }
    get firstName() {
        return this._firstName;
    }
    set firstName(firstName){
        this._firstName = firstName;
    }
    get surname() {
        return this._surname;
    }
    set surname(surname){
        this._surname = surname;
    }
    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }
    set age(age){
        this._age = age;
    }

    get gender() {
        return this._gender;
    }
    set gender(gender){
        this._gender = gender;
    }

    get friends() {
        return this._friends;
    }
    set friends(friends){
        this._friends = friends;
    }

}

var osobe = [];


   $(function() {$.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Steffzz/
   damnz/master/data.json', function(data) 
    {
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

        for(person of json)
        {

            var id = person['id']  ;
            var firstName = person['firstName'] ;
            var surname = person['surname'] ;
            var age = person['age'] ;
            var gender= person['gender'] ;  
            console.log("json is:",JSON.stringify(json,undefined,3));
            var friends = person['friends'].map(
            function(friendId){console.log("friendID is:",friendId);
            var friend = json.find(function(person){return 
            person.id===friendId;});
            console.log("friend is:",JSON.stringify(friend,undefined,2));
            return {
                     firstName:friend.firstName,
                     surname:friend.surname
                                        }
                                }
                );

            var x = new Osoba(id,firstName,surname,age,gender,friends); 
            osobe.push(x);
        }     
        console.log(osobe);
        document.write(JSON.stringify(osobe[6]));

     }) 
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you print out the full "root" level object/array?

Comment: Each person has an IDs in friends array ( but i had to made it to print me their names instead of IDs) This is my print out now http://prntscr.com/ia9um6 am i possible to access friends of these friends whom are not connected to the object i m printing ?

Comment: please use the image service from Stack Overflow (with imgur link) to post images. (image button when you edit your question)

Comment: okay i will , thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the title of your question I understand this structure:

```
const rootArray = 
[
    [
        { 
            key1: ['item1','item2'],
            key2: ['item3', 'item4']
        },

    ]
]

console.log(rootArray[0][0]["key2"][1]);

// Will print 'item4'
```

**Edit after you posted screen shot:**

Since they are not in the object you are printing, you simply have no data to fetch for the object itself. It's just not there.
You need to pick up some sort of uniqueId or some other identifier from each of these friends, and query your database (or wherever you store the entire list of users and their connections) and pick up the other friends.

Comment: so i need to make a new variable within my object that will store friends of their freinds but the problem is that i dont know how to access them

Comment: Where is that data stored?

Comment: osobe = [] is my empty array and at the end of the loop as you can see var x = new Osoba(id,firstName,surname,age,gender,friends); 
            osobe.push(x);    so therefore all my data is stored within osobe array and now i have to access certain person then persons friends (person.friends) then friends of persons friends whom are not connected with person ( person.friends.friends and not friend of person)